# Laravel routing issues: automatically redirect to the root folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes, laravel-routing

i'm newbie in the laravel world and have some routing problems.

I've new laravel installation with the Project name lara located on the local server

```
localhost/lara
```

I have the follow route `Route::get('/lara', function() { return 'test content'; });`

but if I try to open

```
localhost/lara/public/lara
```

I will redirect automatically to the root folder

```
localhost/lara
```

could somebody help me.
thank you

Comment: **I have the follow route     Route::get('/lara', function()
{ return 'test content';
});**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to achieve that. Put it at the bottom of your `route` file or somewhere else as you wish.

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    if (Request::is('*public/*')) return Redirect::to('/lara');

    App::abort(404, 'Page not found');
});
```

Comment: I've try it but did not work :(
I think this is essential .htaccess  routing Problem, because the view is exactly named like the public folder 'lara'.

Comment: I've try it somethig like that.  - - - - - - - - `RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/lara
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`     but still did not work

Answer (score 0):

Just for others with this issue, it could just be that you've not done a

`composer update`